# Regex for Nginx

Tags: regex, apache, nginx, wildcard

I am looking to grant access to one folder in every user's home directory via nginx,

```
location /home/*/share{
}
```

The asterisk `*` doesn't work, but worked in Apache. Could someone tell me the wildcard or regex for it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you written it means that the `/` is the one that could appear multiple times, ie `/home///////share`, to fix it write soemthing like

```
location ~ /home/[^/]+/share {
}
```

Comment: Don't use a star, but a plus. I don't think he wants /home/share to be a match.